# How i can run t-sql script with error exception

Tags: t-sql

I have text column in table, where save date, date saved in 21.02.2012 and 2012-02-21 format, and i want convert all date to 2012-02-21
How i run this script with error exception
`update AdvancedFieldsValues set value=(CONVERT(date, value, 104)) where field_id=801`

Comment: I assume your text column is a char or varchar column and not a text column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update AdvancedFieldsValues
set value = convert(char(10), convert(date, value, 104), 120)
where field_id=801
```

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Fara – Add `and value like '%.%'` to the where clause.

Comment: Thank you very much. Work with `and value not like '%-%'`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson and Fara - I had written: and value like '%[0-3][0-9].[0-1][0-9].[1-2][0,9][0-9][0-9]' -- To handle that, but with the wherestatement in the question i assumed it was just for a specific row. So I didn't post that part